# How to get advanced UI in jBPM?

Tags: user-interface, layout, controls, jbpm

I'm trying to get some attractive-looking UI of jBPM 6.0 Form Modeler -- real life processes usually require that. The question is how to get this by out-of-the-box or at least pluggable means of jBPM? Here I'm using PrimeFaces components as examples of what I'd like to achieve.

**1. Controls**

Controls, provided out-of-the-box, are rather basic (text, number, date)... Is it possible to plug in or at least to develop advanced components? Like:

- www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/oneMenu.xhtml
- www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/oneRadio.xhtml
- www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/basic.xhtml
- www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/treetable/basic.xhtml

**2. Layout**

Again, OOTB layout is ok for trivial cases. Advanced must-haves:

- www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/panel/tabView.xhtml
- www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/panel/accordionPanel.xhtml

**3. Conditional Rendering**

Very often you need to show/hide some field (or even an entire section of fields) based on process context or even on current user input.

E.g. there is a field on a form 'Marital Status', and in case 'Married' is selected, section 'Spouse Details' should show itself.

**4. Validation**

Real life process validation includes cases like "this date must not be in the past" or "this date must not be before that date". Is there some mechanism for custom validation?

**5. Modal Dialogs**

Sometimes you need to show/ask user for something, using a modal dialog:

- www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/overlay/dialog/basic.xhtml

Answer (score 0):

so, do you want to write your own forms using PrimeFaces and then plug that into the KIE Workbech / jBPM Console? or your own PrimeFaces application? Sounds as a good use case, but we don't provide support for Primefaces integration yet (inside KIE workbench), but we can make that happen. If you can expose your forms so they can be embedded into an iframe we can create a simple mechanism to embed them into the tasks.

HTH

Comment: The preferrable case would be to have all aforementioned funcationality (pp 1-5) built-in jBPM, because it's always easier to use one product than several.

So the first question is whether this is possible using just jBPM.



The other case is to somehow plug another product(s) (Primefaces, ...) for custom components, layout and even the whole portal.

So the second question is how can this be achieved.